# iMacros + FF : Linux, command line

Tags: linux, firefox, imacros

I want to run iMacros script with Firefox, under Ubuntu, by specifying the script in the command line. Unfortunately, the browser only opens the file as text and not runs it...

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manually add the macro to your browser then save it under a name of your choice. Then you can call it with

```
    firefox  http://run.imacros.net/?m=name_of_the_macro.iim
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed your macro code into a local test.htm file and run this file via firefox command line (works even with free iMacros version)

Command line example is:

```
firefox file:///home/test/test.htm
```

The test.htm file example is:

```
<html>
   <body onload="window.setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'criimlaunch\').click();', 1000);">

      <script>
         var macroCode = '';
!!!ADD YOUR MACRO HERE!!!
         macroCode += 'PROMPT HELLO!\n';
         macroCode += 'URL GOTO=http://imacros.net/\n';
         macroCode += 'PROMPT BYE!\n';
!!!ADD YOUR MACRO HERE!!!
         function launchMacro()
            {
            try
               {
                  if(!/^(?:chrome|https?|file)/.test(location))
                  {
                     alert('iMacros: Open webpage to run a macro.');
                     return;
                  }
               
                  var macro = {}; 
                  macro.source = macroCode;
                  macro.name = 'EmbeddedMacro';
               
                  var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
                  evt.initCustomEvent('iMacrosRunMacro', true, true, macro);
                  window.dispatchEvent(evt);
               }
            catch(e)
            {
               alert('iMacros Bookmarklet error: '+e.toString());
            };
         }
      </script>

      <a id="criimlaunch" href="javascript:launchMacro();">Launch iMacros</a>

   </body>
</html>
```

See more at:
https://wiki.imacros.net/Webextensions#Add_File_Access